# Adding topics to EthFilter throws an invalid argument length error

Tags: web3j

I am attempting to create an EthFilter which will listen for events from a specific contract

`final EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, null, "0x123...789");`

I want to filter out events based on `topic_1` of the event, so I added

`filter.addOptionalTopics("0x234...891")`

When running this, I get the following error:

`Caused by: org.web3j.protocol.core.filters.FilterException: Invalid request: invalid argument 0: hex has invalid length 20 after decoding; expected 32 for topic`

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I realised that:

1. Topics are made up of 32 bytes. This is a 64-char hex, or 66-char hex with `0x` prefix
2. Addresses are made up of 20 bytes. This is a 40-char hex, or 42-char hex with `0x` prefix

Turns out, the solution is pretty simple. I created this small static utility to handle this:

```
public class TopicEncoder {

    private final static int TOPIC_BYTE_LENGTH = 32;
    private final static int ADDRESS_BYTE_LENGTH = 20;

    /** Pad the given 20-byte/42-char address to a 32-byte/66-char topic-compatible address */
    public static String encodeAddress(final String address) {
        return "0x"
                + "0".repeat(2 * (TOPIC_BYTE_LENGTH - ADDRESS_BYTE_LENGTH)) // 2 zeros per byte (0x00)
                + address.substring(2);
    }

}
```

Then just do:

`filter.addOptionalTopics(TopicEncoder.encodeAddress("0x234...891"))`